# How can I have one mod rewrite for a cms and another for static pages?

Tags: regex, drupal, mod-rewrite

I currently have a site that has Drupal installed and it has clean urls so the .htaccess file contains the following:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

In addition to this I want to be able to publish static html pages and have them use clean urls as well. I was thinking of differentiating them from the drupal pages by adding a specific keyword e.g. content and maybe having something like below (not sure if this will work) - where I get a url like www.domainname.com/nice-holiday and translate it to 
domainname.com/ftp/pages/nice-holiday.html

```
RewriteRule   ^content/(.+)$   domainname.com/ftp/pages/$1.html   [L]
```

The problem is the first rule will try to execute against all requests. I have tried putting the more specific rule before the more general rule but it still doesnt work.
How can you have two mod rewrite rules based on a condition? e.g. presence of a particular word? and more generally has anyone had experience handling a CMS and static pages on the one website - or is that asking for trouble?

Answer (score 0):

This is where RewriteCond comes in handy.

```
# make sure no rewriting is done for requests without www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domainname\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?content/
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# later on...
# don't want this rule to apply for non-www requests either
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domainname\.com
RewriteRule ^/?content/(.+)$ http://domainname.com/ftp/pages/$1.html [L]
```

I think this is what you're going for?  You can eliminate the %{HTTP_HOST} conditions completely if you don't actually care about the www thing.  The two rules can still coexist as long as you keep the `%{REQUEST_URI}` condition on the drupal rewrite, so drupal rewrites explicitly do not apply for URIs beginning with the /content/ prefix.